# Multiple inserts of batch insert over the wire?

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk-insert

I am generating about 500 records.

What I want to do is `INSERT` them all at the same time because:

- The server is located elsewhere and I would rather send one big payload over.
- This seems like less overhead than sending 500 separate insert queries over the wire.

But because they're batch inserting, I don't want to rollback everything if one insert fails - I want to try to insert the rest in there and record the failure(s).

What's the best way to do this in SQL Server? Is `BULK INSERT` what I want?

Comment: `one insert fails` what is the expected error(for what reason do you think it will fail) ? depending of it , you can have different approach ; My first idea , is to have a staging table (no constraints, no PK,no FKs,..) , where you can dump your records.

Comment: what tool are you using on the client side ? command line or application with ADO.NET for instance ?

Comment: i think one important question is not answer.how you are connecting to remote server ?db to db or any web service ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not saying this is *the **best** way*, but here is ***one way***.

My solution uses `xml` which, I think, has a max size of 2gb.  Table Valued Parameters *would* have been ideal, but they are not supported in remote calls.

Since you are only generating around 500 records, you *probably* won't run into any size limitations.

---

On the source instance, create/load a table to play with. This will be the source data to send to the remote process.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.customer
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL
    ,[Name] [varchar](30) NULL
    ,[RecordCreated] [datetime] NULL
    ,[RecordUpdated] [datetime] NULL
    ,
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (1, N'James', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:16:21.297' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:52:02.427' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (2, N'John', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:41:52.347' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:41:52.347' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (3, N'Sam', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:50:25.430' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:50:25.430' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (1, N'James', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:16:21.297' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:52:02.427' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (2, N'John', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:41:52.347' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:41:52.347' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID], [Name], [RecordCreated], [RecordUpdated]) VALUES (3, N'Sam', CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:50:25.430' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-11-01T16:50:25.430' AS DateTime))
GO
```

---

Here is some TSQL to run on the source instance, but before you can fully execute it, you'll have to define the *receiving* stored procedure on the remote server.  I'll get to that.

```
--Declare XML variable and populate by selecting from a table using FOR XML AUTO
DECLARE @x XML = (
        SELECT *
        FROM Customer
        FOR XML AUTO
            ,TYPE
            ,ROOT('Root')
        );

--You cant ship XML via remote call, so declare a Varchar(max) variable and convert the XML
DECLARE @XVarchar VARCHAR(max)
SET @XVarchar = convert(VARCHAR(max), @x)

--Call the remote stored procedure and pass the xml
--My linked server is called sqlcompare

--NOTE: you cannot execute this until you have defined the 
--receiving stored procedure on the remote server.
EXEC sqlcompare.scutility.dbo.[ProcessXmlRows] @xVarchar
```

---

Now, on the remote server, create a stored procedure to receive the passed `xml`.  In the following example, I'm using `OPENXML` to basically shred the `xml` and inserting directly into the remote table. You'd probably need a cursor to help you weed out the good and bad rows. Note, that I have also created the `customer` table on the remote server (this allows me to reference that table in the `OPENXML` using the `WITH` clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessXmlRows] (@Xml xml)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intXMLDocID INT -- xml document handle

--Prepare the XML that was passed into the SP
EXECUTE [master].dbo.sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc = @intXMLDocID OUTPUT
    ,@xmltext = @xml;

--Using OPENXML, and referencing the existing customer table, insert the rows
insert into Customer
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@intXMLDocID, '/Root/Customer') WITH customer

select * from Customer

END
GO
```

Note, that I'm using `with customer` on the `OPENXML`.  From the documentation on [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql)

> The WITH clause provides a rowset format (and additional mapping
>   information as required) by using either SchemaDeclaration or
>   specifying an existing TableName.

---

At this point, you *should* be able to successfully execute the *source* T-SQL to call the remote stored procedure and process the data.

Comment: IMHO,i do not agree with answer provided.you have just address minor problem.How to send 500 records ?how to record " BACK " failed record ?More over "You'd probably need a cursor to help you weed out the good and bad rows" why you suggest cursor when you are not sure of biz. rule to exclude records.